# Php, Windows, how to capture what a running batch file doing?

Tags: php, batch-file

Since it runs long, and prints a lot of information, I dont want to wait until it has run, I want to capture its content while its running. Is it possible? If I could do it with `exec()` it would wait until its over

Comment: could you maybe have the batch file just write to a file whatever it's current status is and read that with php?

Comment: but that would wait until it the batch finishes, I dont want it

Comment: What you want to do is quite complex. Most likely you need to run this batch script in the background and have it write its output to a file. Then you need to create some kind of JS applications that will call a PHP script at regular intervals. And this script will return the last lines that have been written.

Comment: See if this link helps you: http://serverfault.com/questions/7263/convenient-windows-equivalent-to-tail-f-logfile You want soemhting like tail on linux

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with `popen`. Example:

```
<?php
$command = ('ping stackoverflow.com');
$handle = popen ($command,'r');
while (!feof($handle))
{
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
    echo $buffer;
}
pclose($handle);
?>
```

In a Windows-batchfile don't forget the `exit` (http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php#77723).